# Is there any way to tell if a new transaction is started in JTA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jta

I am using Wildfly as my Java EE server. We have a framework that we are using to implement kind of Command Design Pattern.

I'll try to describe the workflow as simple as I can:

- Every Command is an entity that stores the info about the command(timestamp of execution, success status etc..)
- Every Command has it's CommandEJB in which the businesslogic is executed
- All our commands are extented from the Command class, and their EJBs are extended from CommandEJB class
- CommanEJB invokes the run method which is overridden for the specific command, where the business logic is executed for that specific command
- After that the CommandEJB tries to persist the Command object(which carries the info about the command execution as described in point 1)
- If a CommandEJB implementation is making an entity and persisting it in it's implementation of run method, than we always make a bidirectional assotiation between the specific command and that entity

I'll try to write some pseud-code to explain how it works:

I have an entity called Person and I have a CreatePersonCmd which is the command that should create a new person and persist it to the database. After that the framework persists the CreatePersonCmd to the database. On command execution, the Person entity and the CreatePersonCmd entity are linked by

`person.setCmd(cmd);` and

```
cmd.setPerson(person);
```

I have a SAOP Web Service that calls the command:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class MyWebService {
CreatePersonCmd cmd = new CreatePersonCmd();
executor.execute(cmd);
}
```

My CreatePersonCmd is the owner of the relationship between the CreatePersonCommand and Person so that looks like this:

```
public class CreatePersonCmd {
@JoinColumn
@OneToOne
private Person person;
}
```

On the other side of relation is Person:

```
public class Person{
@OneToOne(mappedBy="person")
private CreatePersonCmd createPersonCmd;
}
```

In my CreatePersonEJB(whose run method implementation is invoked):

```
public class CreatePersonCmdEJB extends CommandEJB {

public void run() {

    Person person = new Person("John Doe");
    createPersonCmd.setPerson(person);
    person.setCreatePersonCmd(createPersonCmd);
    em.persist(person);

}
```

After that the CommandEJB continues it's execution and tries to save the command:

```
em.persist(createPersonCmd);
```

However, the execution never gets to this last line, and I get an exception at:

```
em.persist(person);
```

The exception is:

```
Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation
```

The strange thing is that if I make Person the owner of the relationship, then everything works fine.

I made a simple example without our framework that has 2 entities Customer and Address that also have bidirectional OneToOne relation and however I do the testing it always commits fine, whatever order of persisting I use.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
Customer c = new Customer("John Doe");
Address a = new Address("MyStreet", 1123);

c.setAddress(a);
a.setCustomer(c);

em.persist(c);
em.persist(a);
```

No matter what the order of persisting is (address or customer first it always commits fine if I have both lines)

However, in our framework it seems like the trasactions ends after em.persist(person), and I see no em.flush() in our framework source code.

**Is there any way I can know if I am in the same transaction?** I tried to get the transaction by `em.getTransaction()` but I get `A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()`, probably because the transatcions in Java EE are managed by the application container.

Comment: `em.isJoinedToTransaction()` should tell you if the `em` is associated with an active transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If createPersonCmd is already inserted then you must add it to your current working set.
That can be done by

```
createPersonCmd = em.merge(createPersonCmd)
```